# How to find the type of a selected file after Picking the file via an Intent in Android?

Tags: android, file, android-intent, types

I can pick a file that is PDF or image by the following code:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            String[] mimetypes = {"image/*", "application/pdf"
            };
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a file"),REQUEST_GET_SINGLE_FILE);
```

I receive the result in the following method:

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       try {
           if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
              if (requestCode == REQUEST_GET_SINGLE_FILE ) {
                 Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                 ....
                 ....
```

I need to find that the selected file is a PDF or an image? How can I find the type of file?

Comment: Use the content resolver to query the selected uri for mime type.

Comment: Could you please help me more vie code or ...?

Comment: Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to have a read to [`ContentResolver documentation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#getType(android.net.Uri)) and then read this [`Retriefe-info documentation`](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/retrieve-info) then you'll be able to get the extension of your file.

### MIME type

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
String mimeType = getContentResolver().getType(selectedImageUri);
```

It will return something like this :

> "image/jpeg"

> "image/png"

If you want to use a `Cursor` you can do it as :

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImageUri, null, null, null, null);
   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(0);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        String extension = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf(".") + 1); //will return pdf
   }
cursor.close();
```

Comment: The first option is great. The second option (`filePath.substring()`) breaks on lots and lots of `Uri` values.

Comment: Indeed. As column .DATA is queried i think (why 0?) and not column MIME_TYPE which is the one that should be used.